# CreateUserWizard and ContinueButton control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider

1)

A) One of the *CreateUserWizard’s* optional controls is also *ContinueButton* control. This control raises *ContinueButtonClick* event ( if *CommandName* is set to *Continue* ), but what is the purpose of this event? Thus, when should *ContinueButton* control be used?

B) *CreatingUser* event is raised by clicking on CreateUserWizardstep’s *CreateUser* button. I assume clicking on *CreateUser* also raises *NextButtonClick* event?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your (A) question. Here is the sample scenario: Let's say before you create a user, you need to validate whether a particular user id or a particular email address has been taken before or registered before in the database.

So in the first phase, you can ask the new user to insert his/her intended user id ,and email address, and then you can perform validation to check whether it's exist or not in the database. If it's exist, you can display an error message accordingly, and if it's not exist, you can move on to the next phase/wizard, to obtain more details before creating the user in the database.

So for the conclusion, the "Next" button is used to navigate between steps in the creating user wizard steps.

Regarding your (B) question.

According to the [NextButtonClickEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.nextbuttonclick.aspx) documentation, this event is only triggered when "next" button is called.

If i am not mistaken, at the last phase of the wizard steps, there will only be "Create User" button and not "Next", since that phase is the last step in the wizard steps.

Regards,

hadi